# Moving Excel file from one folder to another folder in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I need to move one excel file from one folder into another folder in SSIS Pacakge.
I have used **File System Task** and in there i am giving source folder a file [but that file changes every one hour dynamically ] so how can i set source field file dynamically.

Comment: Where is the alue of the file's path coming from? Is it the only file is the source folder, or will it always have a specific prefix? If so, you can use a ForEach Loop Container to assign the name of the file to a variable.

Comment: Also why have you tagged SSIS 2008 and 2012? Which are you using? 2008 is completely unsupported and lacks a lot of functionality taken for granted in 2012+.